# Truffle migrate Server Error (on truffle init demo)

Tags: ethereum, truffle, consensys-truffle

I'm a DAPP beginner, and am trying to get up and running with the Truffle framework. I've been walking through the Truffle docs, but it doesn't work out of the box for me.

- Create directory, cd into it, and run 'truffle init'
- Run 'truffle compile'
- Run testrpc in a second terminal window, same project directory
- Run 'truffle migrate'

This is the error I get from truffle:

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js


Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Server error
    at Object.module.exports.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
```

I get this with Node v5 & v6. 
Truffle v2.1.1.
Web3 and ether-pudding are installed as truffle dependencies.
TestRPC/0.8.7/darwin/python2.7.12.

Thanks for the help-

Comment: Welcome!  The [Ethereum StackExchange](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com) would have more people able to answer the question.  (I'd answer it but don't know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truffle migrate does run correctly. I've reposted my issue with testrpc here: 
[Testrpc error: 'no loggers could be found for logger 'jsonrpc.manager'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065108/testrpc-error-no-loggers-could-be-found-for-logger-jsonrpc-manager)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you did run testrpc in a second window and let it run? This is important as testrpc in that case is yoir blockchain. If it does not run you will get similar errors as what you describe.
To keep it simple, I also suggest as a start that you do not run another client while running testrpc (geth, parity, mist, ... )

So in short, do a reboot, start testrpc, make sure it does not display errors, then run the truffle migrate command while testrpc still runs in the background.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing.. it's a strange error. In testrpc, this is the output when I run 'truffle migrate': `Listening on localhost:8545
127.0.0.1 - - [2016-12-07 20:44:14] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 718 0.001816
No handlers could be found for logger "jsonrpc.manager"`.  Could there be other network connections interferring? I currently don't have any others running that I know of... On a Mac, 10.12.1.

Comment: According to the NEW error message you are getting, the initial problem is now solved and you are running into a new one. For the new issue, I would recommend opening another question and making the current one as resolved. This will help other resolving their issues easier and faster.