# Testrpc error: 'no loggers could be found for logger 'jsonrpc.manager'

Tags: truffle, consensys-truffle

I'm trying to run `truffle init` and get the sample contract running. I run `truffle init`, `truffle compile`, & `truffle migrate`. In a separate terminal window (same directory as the project), I run testrpc with no errors-- I get the 10 hashes I'm supposed to get.

In testrpc, this is the output when I run `truffle migrate`:

```
Listening on localhost:8545 127.0.0.1 - - [2016-12-07 20:44:14] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 718 0.001816 
No handlers could be found for logger "jsonrpc.manager".
```

Could there be other network connections interfering? I currently don't have any others running that I know of. On a Mac, 10.12.1.

Comment: I've noticed in a lot of tutorial / walk throughs for Truffle, folks on earlier versions aren't running into any issues like this. Is there a possible version incompatibility issue between Truffle and testrpc? I don't have any other servers running on any other ports.

Answer (score 1):

to /bin/testrpc or /usr/local/bin/testrpc (wherever you have testrpc installed) add the following lines:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
```

This will give you actual logging output and show you what you need to fix. In my case, it was a gas-related error.